# Wi-fi is working on guest machine but not on host

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtual-machine

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and sometimes the wi-fi doesn't work. It is connected and isn't showing any errors in the router's page But I can't access the internet.

Sometimes some devices connected to the wi-fi can access the internet while others don't. There isn't any configuration on the router to block some devices. It happens randomly.

But my guest machine (windows 10 machine on Virtualbox) can always access the internet even when the host machine can't.

Network settings on my virtual machine is Bridged Adapter. Also it has guest addition extension installed.

Comment: Sound like an IP conflict of some sort. What do you mean by "I can't access the internet"? Do you mean accessing web pages through the browser? How about pinging an IP on the internet? Did you try a traceroute?